# ¿Como enviar lo escrito en un edit text a mi Email presionando un boton?

Tags: android-studio

Tengo 5 'edit texts' y un botón, ¿Cómo hago para que la información que escribo en el EditText al presionar el 'Button' se envié a mi email

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtNombre,txtCip,txtDNI,txtCel,txtEmail;
    Button btnIniciar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtNombre=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        txtCip=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCip);
        txtDNI=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDNI);
        txtCel=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCel);
        txtEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

        btnIniciar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnIniciar);

        btnIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override



        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente necesitas definir el método `onClick()` del listener y dentro agregas el código necesario para el envío del texto contenido dentro del `EditText` (por cierto no defines cual `EditText`) , como ejemplo el EditText `txtNombre`:

```
 btnIniciar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnIniciar);

        btnIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
               enviarEmail(txtNombre.getText().toString());
            } 

        });
```

Este serìa un mètodo para envío de email:

```
public void  enviarEmail(String mensaje){

  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

  emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
  emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "tuemail@email.com"); // * configurar email aquí!
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Tu Asunto...");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mensaje); 

  try {
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar email."));        
     Log.i("EMAIL", "Enviando email...");
  }
  catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "NO existe ningún cliente de email instalado!.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un método como este:

```
public void enviarEmail(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Asunto de prieba");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Probando el envio");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email@gmail.com"});
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Si no mal recuerdo te abrirá una nueva ventana donde especificas algunas cosas.

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres que se te abra una ventana nueva y enviar el mail directamente al pulsar el botón puedes utilizar una librería que lo haga directamente. Yo suelo utilizar Javamail. Te dejo un enlace para su uso

http://mrbool.com/how-to-work-with-java-mail-api-in-android/27800

Espero que te valga